# Is it possible to have an unplayable tile?

Tags: carcassonne

Is it possible to have a scenario where you pick a tile up, and are unable to make a legal placement with it?

What happens in this scenario?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I found this rule very quickly in the [rules](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=462).

> In the rare circumstance where a drawn tile has no legal placement
>   (and all players agree), the player discards the tile from the game
>   (into the box) and draws another tile to place

For example:
[image]

Comment: An example of when this could happen in the base game is if the starting city is closed off and you draw the tile that is just city interior with no borders.

Comment: The River Expansion tends to nullify this probability...

Comment: The river expansion does not nullify this probability.  I have encountered unplayable tiles with it - very occasionally.

Comment: The shown example is just the shortest play to get to a non-playable tile.  I have certainly seen it come up well into the game as well.